# Enviar dois dados pelo ajax

Tags: ajax

Seguinte, tenho um código ajax que pega valores d um formulário e envia pra uma página. Porém preciso enviar junto um retorno que já obtive em um trecho ajax.

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {

          var dados = new FormData(this);

          $.ajax({
            contentType: "charset=UTF-8",
            url: 'buscar.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"html",
            data: dados,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function (data) {              
              $('.primeira').hide();
              $('.segunda').show();
              $('#resultado').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Esse código acima eu recebo uma lista array e exibo no #resultado. Como eu envio esse resultado para uma outra página juntamente com a respota de um formulário?

```
        $('#form2').on('submit', function (e) {

        var dados = new FormData(this);
        var id = $('#resultado').val();

        $.ajax({
        contentType: "charset=UTF-8",
        url: 'lista.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"html",
        data: {dados, id},
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function (data) {
            $('.segunda').hide();
            $('#resultado').html(data);
            $('.terceira').show();            
        }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Aqui acima está a parte em que eu envio um segundo formulário... Porem como envio o que tem na div #resultado junto?

Answer (score 0):

Como no primeiro Ajax você usou `$('#resultado').html(data);`, supõe-se que o elemento `#resultado` seja uma div (ou outro elemento que aceita conteúdo interno). Logo, no segundo Ajax você deve usar o mesmo método `.html()` para pegar esse conteúdo, ou seja:

```
var id = $('#resultado').html();
```

E no `data`, passar esse valor no parâmetro `id`:

```
data: {dados, id: id},
```